# netfilter-like kernel module to get source and destination address

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I read [this guide](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-filter-network-packets-using-netfilterpart-2-implement-the-hook-function/) to write a kernel module to do simple network filtering.

First, I have no idea of what below text this means, and what's the difference between inbound and outbound data packet(by transportation layer)?

> When a packet goes in from wire, it travels from physical layer, data
>   link layer, network layer upwards, therefore it might not go through
>   the functions defined in netfilter for skb_transport_header to work.

Second, I hate magic numbers, and I want to replace the `20` (the length of typical IP header) with any function from the linux kernel's utilities([source file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/skbuff.h)).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article is a little outdated now. Text that you don't understand is only applicable to kernel versions below 3.11.

## For new kernels (>= 3.11)

If you are sure that your code will only be used with kernels >= 3.11, you can use next code for both **input** and **output** packets:

```c
udp_header = (struct udphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
```

Or more elegant:

```c
udp_header = udp_hdr(skb);
```

It's because **transport header** is already set up for you in [ip_rcv()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/ip_input.c?v=3.11#L437):

```c
skb->transport_header = skb->network_header + iph->ihl*4;
```

This change was brought by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=21d1196a35f5686c4323e42a62fdb4b23b0ab4a3).

## For old kernels (< 3.11)

#### Outgoing packets (`NF_INET_POST_ROUTING`)

In this case `.transport_header` field set up correctly in `sk_buffer`, so it points to actual **transport layer** header (UDP/TCP). So you can use code like this:

```c
udp_header = (struct udphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
```

or better looking (but actually the same):

```c
udp_header = udp_hdr(skb);
```

#### Incoming packets (`NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING`)

This is the tricky part.

In this case the `.transport_header` field is not set to the actual **transport layer** header (UDP or TCP) in `sk_buffer` structure (that you get in your netfilter hook function). Instead, `.transport_header` points to IP header (which is **network layer** header).

So you need to calculate address of **transport header** by your own. To do so you need to skip IP header (i.e. add IP header length to your `.transport_header` address). That's why you can see next code in the article:

```c
udp_header = (struct udphdr *)(skb_transport_header(skb) + 20);
```

So `20` here is just the length of IP header.

It can be done more elegant in this way:

```c
struct iphdr *iph;
struct udphdr *udph;

iph = ip_hdr(skb);

/* If transport header is not set for this kernel version */
if (skb_transport_header(skb) == (unsigned char *)iph)
    udph = (unsigned char *)iph + (iph->ihl * 4); /* skip IP header */
else
    udph = udp_hdr(skb);
```

In this code we use an actual IP header size (which is `iph->ihl * 4`, in bytes) instead of magic number `20`.

Another magic number in the article is `17` in next code:

```c
if (ip_header->protocol == 17) {
```

In this code you should use `IPPROTO_UDP` instead of `17`:

```c
#include <linux/udp.h>

if (ip_header->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
```

## Netfilter input/output packets explanation

If you need some reference about difference between incoming and outgoing packets in netfilter, see the picture below.

[image: netfilter-hooks]

Details:

[1]: [Some useful code from GitHub](https://github.com/clan/kernel/blob/master/net/pkt_chk.c)

[2]: ["Linux Kernel Networking: Implementation and Theory" by Rami Rosen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143026196X)

[3]: [This answer may be also useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553990/print-tcp-packet-data/29584449#29584449)

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out 17 as IPPROTO_UDP, I have digged out that before posting the answer.