# Respond to a Packet Received in The NetFilter at Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, hook, kernel-module, netfilter

I'm working on Linux 4.13.x. And I'm considering to send a packet response in the kernel.

Consider an echo TCP or UDP server running in the userland and there is also another node running a TCP or UDP client. Clients are sending requests to the server. I want to send the packet response back to the client without any involvement of server application running at userspace.

Here is my thoughts about this problem:

I started thinking how it is possible and I come across to a solution like **netfilter**. If I can capture the packets in **NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING** and then try to swap the source and destination IP addresses of IP header and also swapping the ports in the TCP header, then according to [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656012/netfilter-like-kernel-module-to-get-source-and-destination-address/29663558#29663558) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553990/print-tcp-packet-data/29584449?noredirect=1#comment85376135_29584449) presumably modified packet should be forwarded to the originator throughout the **routing system**.

Actually, I tried this scenario and it seems it is not possible to do so from netfilter hooks, however, I'm not sure of it. I thought that it is not working since it has problem with checksums because I'm manipulating packets so I did another experiment to figure this issue out. I just change the packet data and everything worked well. I think checksums don't have any problem since they will be check at NIC while receiving and also same situation while sending so manipulation in between doesn't make anything wrong. I also activate the IPv4 forwarding at the server host(sysctl.config) still nothing changes.

I don't want to create new packet, I only want to alter this packet and send it back. There is another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071054/how-to-echo-a-packet-in-kernel-space-using-netfilter-hooks) which is creating another packet. Moreover, I'm just thinking why this scenario is not working? But based on the netfilter's architecture it should work.

Thank you

Comment: Just a guess; try setting `skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OTHERHOST` and `skb->_skb_refdst = 0`. I haven't read through all the routing code but this might take care of it. This may or may not break your routing stack; I have no idea.

Comment: @JoelC thank you for your comment, I tried your idea but it didn't work. Just one question where did you check exactly for routing code at kernel?!

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on this, actually kernel validate the source ip address after ip_rcv function in NF_HOOK which check the source ip address. So just try below command:-

```
sudo sysctl -w "net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0"
```

after doing this also disable your interface from which you send and receive packet just like below:-

```
sudo sysctl -w "net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.rp_filter=0"
```